# crud operation on backbone js where data come from database

Tags: backbone.js

I want to create a crud operation in backbone js where the data is coming from database.I cant understand where i put ajax call in my backbone example. please help.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're not grokking the "Backbone way" yet.  In Backbone, you (generally speaking) don't put any AJAX calls anywhere in your code, as all the AJAX logic you need is already in Backbone's code.

What your code does need to provide are the "missing pieces" that make your app unique.  For instance, let's say you want to "get" (ie. perform the "R" in "CRUD") a Foo with an ID 55  in Backbone.  You would make a Foo class like so:

```
var Foo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'www.example.com/yourServerPathForFoos'
});
```

then you would create an instance of it:

```
var foo55 = new Foo({id: 55});
```

then you would make Backbone do the AJAX work for you by invoking the fetch command:

```
foo55.fetch();
```

That will make Backbone start an AJAX request, and when that request comes back Backbone will populate `foo55` with whatever data came back.  You can provide any jQuery AJAX option, and Backbone will either pass them along to jQuery or do something similar to what jQuery would have done with them.

For instance, to do something when the AJAX call resolves, you can do:

```
foo55.fetch({success: doSomething});
```

There are similar Backbone methods for the other parts of CRUD too:

C - save

R - fetch

U - save (with a  `{patch: true}` argument)

D - destroy